# DHARMa with distribution gamma

Tags: r, glmmtmb

I am analyzing some latency data, with a gamma distribution and using a glmmtmb model.
The problem arises when I want to do a dharma to this model and I get this error.

```
m1 <- glmmTMB(formula = Lat.Min ~ Fruta,
              family  = Gamma(link = "log"),
              data    = datos)

library(DHARMa)
simulationOutput <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = m1, refit = T, plot = T) #no converge para
hist(simulationOutput)
testDispersion(simulationOutput)
simulate

Error in UseMethod("family") : 
  no applicable method for 'family' applied to an object of class "glmmTMB"
```

dharma is supposed to support glmmtmb so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Please do not post images of your code for these [reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Also you would have a better chance of getting an answer faster by giving [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.